# PowerReviews email field filled using JQuery but not gets validated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an ecom website and we have PowerReviews integrated with our website. This facilitate users to write a review about a product. We have a requirement that the login user's email address should be auto populated in power review email field. I  have used `window.onload` event to fill this field. I'm successful in populating this field but the problem is: when user fills all the required fields and submit it, it says email field is invalid even valid email address is auto populated in this field. But when I remove a character and type it again, it validates that email address and allows to submit. I have tried many approaches but nothing works. Tried the following:

```
$('#pr-email_collection-input').trigger('blur');
$('#pr-email_collection-input').trigger('keyup');
$('#pr-email_collection-input').trigger('keydown');
$('#pr-email_collection-input').trigger('keypress');
$('#pr-email_collection-input').trigger('focus');
$('#pr-email_collection-input').trigger('change');
```

But nothing worked. Can anyone help out how to validate this field programatically without user interaction with that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found one solution for this and its working fine. We can add an email parameter while calling to the api of PowerReview like following:

```
POWERREVIEWS.display.render({
    merchant_user_email : 'youremailaddress.com'
    //Your other params come here
});
```

The above will render power review form without email address field so you dont need to enter email address and validate it. I hope, this would help others as there is no good documentation available.